# How to make Api response faster While dealing with images

Tags: node.js

im  storing the person details with the image and store the image as a buffer in the mongodb Database using Node js(Express) im saving the image buffer after compressing it after 4 or 5  images  it take about 10 seconds to render them on my react js front end

i tried saving the image as  base64  string ,then i tried saving as buffer then i saved the compress buffer but still facing the same problem